# Can I use just DirectusSDK instead of REST or GraphQL?

Tags: directus

Are there any downsides to use directusSdk instead of making GraphQL requests?

According to documentation; My front-end can log in users and make requests through javascript SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say using the SDK is a great option and is something I choose to do myself where possible, I believe that the Directus application uses it too, therefore it is well looked after